# Aggregate puzzle with $match and date comparison

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am having a puzzle with comparison of dates.  I have created a simplified story to help illustrate.  Imagine the following collection of documents:

```
{ 
    "_id" : "A", 
    "t1" : ISODate("2018-01-23T00:00:00.000+0000")
}
{ 
    "_id" : "B", 
    "t1" : ISODate("2018-01-22T00:00:00.000+0000")
}
{ 
    "_id" : "C", 
    "t1" : ISODate("2018-01-21T00:00:00.000+0000")
}
```

This is three documents with dates in 2018.

Now imagine an aggregation with a `$match` entry that looks as follows:

```
{
  $match:
  {
    "t1": {
      $gte: {
        $dateFromString: {
          dateString: "2017-02-08T12:10:40"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What this should do is match all the documents as the date I am comparing against is back in 2017.  However, what I am finding is that no documents match.  This is the first phase in an aggregation pipeline but with no documents being passed forward, that's the end of the current story.

Can anyone see where I might be going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) (3.6 mongo version ) to use the aggregation functions (`dateFromString`) in the $match stage. $match in its simple form only supports query operators.

Compare [`query operators`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/) vs [`aggregation comparison operators`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-comparison/).

Change to

```
{"$match":{"$expr":{"$gte":["$t1",{"$dateFromString":{"dateString":"2017-02-08T12:10:40"}}]}}}
```

Comment: Thank you kind sir.  Fantastic response.  I tested your recipe and it worked perfectly.   Now I'm going to have to hit the books in depth to determine why it works.  Thank you for the links in the response.  A deep bow in your direction sir.

Comment: NOTE: $expr will not use indexes, with slow down the query drastically....

Answer (score 0):

check out this npm module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb-extended-json it'll automatically convert { '$date': "2016-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"} to a date object for you